# vba excel: Add-in in XLSTART ignored

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

We have a vba excel Add-In installed in the users XLSTART folder. This works fine.

Now we did a small code change in a function and tested it on the developer machine. This works fine as well.

After deploying the Add-In, it's completely ignored by Excel. It's not loaded on start-up, no error message, nothing. If we copy again the old versin to the XLSTART folder, it works as expected. We did the same code change to a Word macro which is installed in the STARTUP folder. This one works fine.

Any ideas why the changed Excel Add-In gets ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons are:
It does not get opened
Permissions or macro security prevent it from functioning
THe original XLA is actually being loaded from somewhere else

I suggest you do some tests:
- When you look at Tools->Addins is the addin checked? If so it has been installed somewhere probably other than XLSTART
- when you place the revised addin in XLStart does it get opened and is it visible in the VBE?
- If you remove it from XLSTART and then open the XLA file as if it was a normal workbook does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the hints! No, it has not been installed from somewehere else. It's not visible in VBE and yes it does open as a normal workbook if I open it directly.

Comment: Did you check if the "old" code might "live" in the PERSONAL file instead of the xla in the xlstart dir? Do you see almost duplicate macro's or functions when you hit [Alt]+[F8]. You did not say if the code stopped working when the xla was removed from xlstart.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem with a user. The reason was that the xla (ours is password protected) was **not read-only**. I know it is ridiculous but the xla was ignored until this changed.

Hopefully this will help others avoid such headaches.